# Kivy - build APK with buildozer on Docker Desktop failed

Tags: docker, kivy, buildozer

I try to generate APK with Buildozer running in Docker container (Docker Desktop on Windows 10), but it fails anytime. The image was pulled from https://hub.docker.com/r/kivy/buildozer. When started with `docker run --volume ${pwd}:/home/user/hostcwd buildozer init`, then buildozer.spec is correctly created, but when I run `docker run --volume ${pwd}:/home/user/hostcwd buildozer debug` then all the fun ends with error message about missing API:

[image]

Unfortunately I'm also quite new in Docker... If I understand it correctly, then SDK and NDK should have been downloaded successfully during the process, but Android API is missing and I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK and NDK are indeed downloaded, as you already guessed, but you must explicitly accept their licenses. You can do this in the `buildozer.spec` file if you set `android.accept_sdk_license = True`.

I generated the `buildozer.spec` file in the working directory

```
docker run --volume "$(pwd)":/home/user/hostcwd kivy/buildozer init
```

Then I have set `android.accept_sdk_license = True` in `buildozer.spec` that was generated in the working directory:

```
...
# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = True

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it did not help - even with this option I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Strange, it worked on my end. I can delete my answer if you think this will increase the chances of getting a better answer